# Google sheets - Countifs across multiple different sheets but the same cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I want to try to create a formula or a script that performs a countif across multiple different sheets (Sheets listed in A2:A1000). I've tried a couple of different things but both seem to not be working as I want them to be.

Formula method :

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(IFERROR(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&A2:A1000&"'!B2:H2"), D1))))`

This method seems to countifs on A2 but stops there, It doesn't count any of the data from any of the other sheets listed in the A2:A1000 range. Is there any work around for this cause the formula method would be preferred.

Script method :

Now the script method works and counts all the data I need across all the sheets... Perfect. Except if the data in any of the tabs changes, I have to delete the `countOccurrencesAcrossSheets(B2:H2, D1)` formula and reinput it. This wouldn't be an issue if it was just one cell I wanted to gather data with but I need about 1000 cells that count across multiple different sheets.

```
function countOccurrencesAcrossSheets(range, value) {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var count = 0;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    var data = sheet.getRange(range).getValues();
    
    for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
      for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
        if (data[row][col] === value) {
          count++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  return count;
}
```

The sheet list is long at A2:A1000 but if this is an issue I could cut this down to 12 max and archive data every 12 weeks.

Anyone know how to make this work?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z-mU1VS-oxG0PDBzfn0ThyG0S4NxrhR3YL60ndzDY6E/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*One more approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(Σ,let(Λ,reduce({"",""},index(to_text(tocol(A2:A,1))),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,reduce({"",""},sequence(7),lambda(x,y,vstack(x,hstack(indirect("'"&c&"'!A2:A"),choosecols(indirect("'"&c&"'!B2:H"),y)))))))),
       filter(Λ,index(Λ,,2)<>"")),
       makearray(counta(C2:C),counta(D1:M1),lambda(r,c,countifs(index(Σ,,1),index(C2:C,r),index(Σ,,2),index(D1:M1,,c)))))
```

- *Use this in Cell_D2 & it expands to right & downwards automatically. make sure there's no other data in this range blocking the formula.*
- *this also takes into account the data directly from the drop-downs from all the date_tabs `B:H` & not from `M:V`*

[image]

Comment: This also worked great, Made it easier as all the other rows were instantly filled in, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MAP function to sum the same cell across different sheets.

```
=LET(sheet_names,A2:A,cell_to_sum,"M2",SUMPRODUCT(MAP(TO_TEXT(sheet_names),LAMBDA(sheet_name,IFERROR(INDIRECT(sheet_name&"!"&cell_to_sum))))))
```

This formula sums cell M2 of all the sheets in A2:A.